# returning xpath attribute

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to return the value for the "**label**" attribute with no success. I am stuck lol

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($source);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$code = $xml->xpath("//toolbarbutton");
var_dump($code);

(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Hello World
                    [cmd] => redirect
                    [mode] => true
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
$attr = $code[0]->attributes();
echo $attr['label'];
```